# Octave not running on Ubuntu 16.04. Give the following error/message

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, octave

After `sudo apt-get update` and the `sudo apt-get install octave` when i type ***octave*** in the terminal I get the following message:

*The settings file*
*/home/ameya/.config/octave/qt-settings*
*does not exist and can not be created.*
*Make sure you have read and write permissions to*
*/home/ameya/.config/octave*

*Octave GUI must be closed now.*

How do I give permission or make the folder that needs to be created?
I'm new to Ubuntu

Comment: Maybe you should ask in https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Well yeah ill put the question up there also, just wanted to know if i could find an answer here. I usually turn to stack-overflow for doubts.

Comment: Yes, but this question is borderline off-topic as its not about programming, but about how to use Ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

This happens when the ownership of a program (octave) changes to root i.e. when you run  ***sudo octave*** from terminal.

To fix this, goto the ***home/.config/octave*** directory and change the ownership for the file '***qt-settings***', by running the below commands:

```
cd .config/octave
sudo chown $USER qt-settings
```